# Refreshing Spring context when JMS message delivered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I'd like to refresh my application context when system receives JMS message. In order to do it, I set up Spring Integration jms:message-driven-channel-adapter which forwards message to service activator implementing ApplicationContextAware. This activator (ConfigurationReloader class) invokes ConfigurableApplicationContext#refresh() method.

Below is sample code snippet:

```
 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsDriverConfigurationAdapter"
    destination="configurationApplyQueue" channel="jmsConfigurationInboundChannel" />

 <channel id="jmsConfigurationInboundChannel"/>

 <service-activator input-channel="jmsConfigurationInboundChannel" ref="configurationReloader" method="refresh"/>
```

And my activator:

```
public final class ConfigurationReloader implements ApplicationContextAware {
        private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public void refresh() {
           this.applicationContext.refresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(
                final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            if (applicationContext instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
                this.applicationContext =
                    (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
            }
        }
    }
```

In case of delivering such message, context start shutdown operation but stuck on DefaultMessageListenerContainer bean shutdown:

```
2011-11-14 15:42:52,980 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer - Shutting down JMS listener container
2011-11-14 15:42:52,980 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer - Waiting for shutdown of message listener invokers
2011-11-14 15:42:55,104 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer#0-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer - Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
```

Invoking this operation over JMS is crucial for me since new configuration parameters are delivered along with message. 
It is standard Spring MVC application with DispatcherServlet on the front based on the latest SpringCore and Spring Integration. Also I am sure that it's JMS related issue, because invoking ConfigurationLoader through controller works fine.

As I've debugged, it stucks after DefaultMessageListenerContainer#538 line invocation (wait() method on lifecycleMonitor):

```
/**
 * Destroy the registered JMS Sessions and associated MessageConsumers.
 */
protected void doShutdown() throws JMSException {
    logger.debug("Waiting for shutdown of message listener invokers");
    try {
        synchronized (this.lifecycleMonitor) {
            while (this.activeInvokerCount > 0) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Still waiting for shutdown of " + this.activeInvokerCount +
                            " message listener invokers");
                }
                this.lifecycleMonitor.wait();   // <--- line 538
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Re-interrupt current thread, to allow other threads to react.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

...there is nobody to call notify / notifyAll on monitor so maybe it's some kind of bug?

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please explain why do you need such sophisticated architecture? Reloading application context when JMS message is received? Sounds crazy (or maybe ingenious?)

Nevertheless, I am not 100% sure but the information you provided is pretty clear: you are trying to shutdown an application context while consuming JMS message. But since the consumer is Spring-managed, context cannot be destroyed because it waits for all beans to finish - including yours `ConfigurationReloader` required by Spring Integration message consumer. And `ConfigurationReloader` cannot finish because it waits for context to be destroyed (`refresh()` is blocking).

Simply put - you have introduced a cyclic dependency and a deadlock.

The solution is simple - delay the context refresh so that it happens after the JMS message consumption. The easiest way would be:

```
public void refresh() {
    Thread destroyThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.applicationContext.refresh();
        }
    };
    destroyThread.start();
}
```

Not pretty but I'm almost sure this will work.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks!
I don't know if it is ingenious but surely a little bit crazy ;) What I'm trying to achieve is some kind of dynamic integration tier. Design of components (and thus, the whole integration layer) is delivered over JMS.

You were right about deadlock. The other solution (maybe even simpler) is to use QueueChannel instead of DirectChannel. Once message is put into queue, DMLC listener thread finish processing. Then, message may be get from the queue and context may be refreshed from the same thread without deadlock.